# ¿como crear una imagen no temporal? android java

Tags: java, android

Intento crear el archivo de una foto pero al momento de crearla solo me crea un archivo temporal y mi app no reconoce las imagenes comparto parte de mi codigo. en android

```
 File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", storageDir);
        rutaImagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: el código que muestras va a crear un archivo con extensión .jpg, esto no sería una imagen propiamente, ¿cómo obtendrías la imagen?

Comment: file imagen=new File(); pero no me sale aun no sabria como crear la imagen. la capturo, pero no la creo

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: 2023-02-14 17:52:16.184 28459-28459/com.example.root.colectapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.root.colectapp, PID: 28459
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.root.colectapp/com.example.root.colectapp.fotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5903)

Comment: y al momento de listar las imagenes supuestamente del directorio donde las almacene me aparece el siguiente error:    2023-02-14 17:54:54.483 29016-29016/com.example.root.xxxx E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Comment: Ok, ya veo, me parece que es el directorio de donde las obtienes, agrega como obtienes "storageDir" y revisa si en ese lugar en verdad estan las imagenes. @Sandii

Answer (score 0):

Como el nombre de la función lo indica, está creando un archivo temporal.

Para crear un archivo, llama al constructor de [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) pasando la ruta del archivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
File archivo = new File("ruta/imagen.png");
```

Luego, llama a la función [`createNewFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()).

Posteriormente puedes crear un `FileOutputStream` para guardar la información.

```
var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(archivo);

// Guarda la imagen
...
```