# guardar la foto tomada android

Tags: java, android-studio

intento guardar una foto que tomo desde la interfaz de captura de fotografia pero no lo consigo comparto parte de mi codigo que implemento para guardar la foto

```
File imagenNueva=new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),imageFileName+".jpg");
 File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", storageDir);
        rutaImagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
        return imagenNueva;
```

Comment: Anteriormente creaste esta pregunta : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/583197/como-crear-una-imagen-no-temporal-android-java Cuál es el problema que tienes en tu código y que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: hola me indica que las imagenes no existen sigo sin porder guardarlas

Comment: Perdón, tal vez me equivoque, pero no debería ser: ***File imagenNueva = new File( getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath( imageFileName+".jpg" ));***

Comment: Si creas un archivo, no significa que es una imagen, deberìas poner el mensaje que se muestra realmente y como deseas obtener la imagen,crearla, descargarla?

Comment: Deberías ver la respuesta que recibiste en la otra pregunta.

Comment: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  es el error que me marca en logcat

Comment: De donde obtienes la imagen, existe en el disco o la tomas de otra parte?

Comment: la tomo con el intent de captura de fotografias

Comment: ya intente varias maneras pero no logro guardarlas